# How to select all hours between two dates?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
declare @minDateTime as datetime;
declare @maxDateTime as datetime;

set @minDateTime = '2014-01-13 02:00:00';
set @maxDateTime = '2014-12-31 14:00:00';
```

I am looking to create a select statement that would return every hour between @minDateTime and @maxDateTime as follows (there is no table to select from. I am not looking for where clause !):

```
2014-01-13 02:00:00
2014-01-13 03:00:00
2014-01-13 04:00:00
...
2014-12-31 12:00:00
2014-12-31 13:00:00
2014-12-31 14:00:00
```

Comment: so there's a good reason you need to do this in Sql instead of c#?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @JohnSaunders I learned once again something new. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this. Use a `Recursive CTE`.

```
DECLARE @minDateTime AS DATETIME;
DECLARE @maxDateTime AS DATETIME;

SET @minDateTime = '2014-01-13 02:00:00';
SET @maxDateTime = '2014-12-31 14:00:00';

;
WITH Dates_CTE
     AS (SELECT @minDateTime AS Dates
         UNION ALL
         SELECT Dateadd(hh, 1, Dates)
         FROM   Dates_CTE
         WHERE  Dates < @maxDateTime)
SELECT *
FROM   Dates_CTE
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

In the above query `Dates_CTE` is a `Common Expression Table`, the base record for the `CTE` is derived by the first sql query before `UNION ALL`. The result of the query gives you the `Minimum date`.

Second query after `UNION ALL` is executed repeatedly to get results. 
This process is **`recursive`** and will continue till the Dates is less than `@maxDateTime`.

Comment: Hello. I got the following msg : The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.

Comment: @Marc - My bad check now

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way using a `Tally Table`:

```
DECLARE @minDateTime DATETIME;
DECLARE @maxDateTime DATETIME;

SET @minDateTime = '2014-01-13 02:00:00';
SET @maxDateTime = '2014-12-31 14:00:00';

DECLARE @hrsDiff INT;
SELECT @hrsDiff = DATEDIFF(HH, @minDateTime, @maxDateTime);

WITH E1(N) AS (
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
),--10E+1 or 10 rows
E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
Tally(N) AS(SELECT row_number() over(order by (select null)) from E4) -- Numbered rrow
SELECT @minDateTime 
UNION ALL
SELECT DATEADD(HH, N, @minDateTime)
FROM Tally
WHERE
    N <= @hrsDiff
```