# SQL calculate points between a time range

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, stored-procedures

I’ve a table which contains different time ranges:

```
Id  Start Time  End Time    Points
1   0:00        3:00        10
2   3:01        6:00        20
3   6:01        23:59       30
```

Now I need to calculate the points achieved between two date ranges with respect to time specified.

```
Start date = 11/9/2016 18:17:00 and 
End date = 11/10/2016 01:20:00
```

I need to calculate the sum of points gained between these two dates.
The time of start date that is 18:17 falls under Id 3, whose point is 30. So the calculation will be,

```
18:17 to 23:59 -> 6 hrs -> 6 * 30 = 180 points
```

The end time 01:20 falls under Id 1

```
0:00 to 1:20 -> 2 hrs 
(if minute is greater than zero, it is rounded to next hour, ie; 2) -> 2 * 10 = 20 points
```

So the total points gained will be 200 points. 
Taking the time difference, does not help me, if the start and end date difference is greater than one day.

**Table Structure:**
Id - int,
StartTime - time(7),
EndTime - time(7),
Points - int

How to write a query for this using SQL?

Comment: What is the data type for your start time and end time columns? Also, what is your date format? `DDMM` or `MMDD`?

Comment: Where do you get your Start and End date? Another table or parameter?

Comment: datatype is time(7)

Comment: from date and two dates are the two parameters that we pass

Comment: Provide more information regarding the table schema

Comment: What you would have to do is create a virtual table using select tatement (similar to [solution to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27161474/how-to-select-all-hours-between-two-dates) ) and then join "points" column to that table. Than do a select with `sum(points)` on this virtal table.

Comment: Just to make sure, minutes on the start time are rounded down, and minutes on the end time are rounded up?

Comment: `18:17 to 23:59 -> 6 hrs -> 6 * 30 = 180 points` this isn't 6 full hours. please clarify the logic.

Comment: Yes, minutes on start time needs to be rounded down and end time minutes needs to be rounded up

Comment: @joe What is sql version?

Comment: SQL Server 2014

Comment: Start date = 11/9/2016 18:17:00 and 
End date = 11/10/2016 01:20:00

It takes start time as 18:00 and end time as 02:00 after rounding it.

It then compares with the time table and takes records, that comes between these two time ranges. That would be Id 1 and 3.

Id  Start Time  End Time    Points
1   0:00        3:00        10
3   6:01        23:59       30

The time difference (Id: 3) of 18:00 - 00:00 (23 will be rounded up) will be 6 hrs and the point corresponding to Id 3 is 30. So multiply it with hours 6 * 30, it will yield result 180.

Comment: @Joe This is posible? `Start date = 11/9/2016 18:17:00 and End date = 11/10/2017 01:20:00` From 2016 to 2017

Comment: Nope... Only 10 days difference will be there maximum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was good.

You can as the below:

```
DECLARE @Tbl TABLE (Id INT, StartTime TIME, EndTime TIME, Points INT)
INSERT INTO @Tbl
VALUES                 
(1,   '0:00',     '3:00' ,       10),
(2,   '3:01',     '6:00' ,       20),
(3,   '6:01',     '23:59',       30)


DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = '2016.11.09 18:17:00'
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME = '2016.11.10 01:20:00'


;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT 1 AS RowId, @StartDate CurrentDate, 0 Point, @StartDate DateVal UNION ALL
    SELECT
        A.RowId ,
        IIF((A.CurrentDate + A.EndTime) > @EndDate, @EndDate, DATEADD(MINUTE, 1, (A.CurrentDate + A.EndTime))) AS CurrentDate,
        A.Points,
        IIF((A.CurrentDate + A.EndTime) > @EndDate, @EndDate, (A.CurrentDate + A.EndTime)) DateVal
    FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            C.RowId + 1 AS RowId,  
            CAST(CAST(CurrentDate AS DATE) AS DATETIME) CurrentDate,
            CAST((SELECT T.EndTime FROM @Tbl T WHERE CAST(CurrentDate AS TIME) BETWEEN T.StartTime AND T.EndTime) AS DATETIME) AS EndTime,
                (SELECT T.Points FROM @Tbl T WHERE CAST(CurrentDate AS TIME) BETWEEN T.StartTime AND T.EndTime) AS Points,
            C.CurrentDate AS TempDate
         FROM CTE C         
    ) A
    WHERE           
        A.TempDate <> IIF((A.CurrentDate + A.EndTime) > @EndDate, @EndDate, DATEADD(MINUTE, 1, (A.CurrentDate + A.EndTime)))
), CTE2
AS
(
    SELECT
        C.RowId ,
        C.CurrentDate ,
        C.Point ,
        C.DateVal,
        DATEDIFF(MINUTE, LAG(C.DateVal) OVER (ORDER BY C.RowId), C.DateVal) MinuteOfDateDiff
    FROM
        CTE C
)


 SELECT 
    SUM(CEILING(C.MinuteOfDateDiff * 1.0 / 60.0) * C.Point)
 FROM 
    CTE2 C
```

Result: `200`

Comment: Working Perfectly... Thanks alot NEER

Comment: Neer, I'm having bit of problem, when the time slots are as listed below:

Id | StartTime | EndTime | Points

12 | 2:01 | 20:00 | 10

14 | 20:01 | 2:00 | 20

The result I get is "NULL"

Parameters: StartDate  = '2016-10-02 00:41:00.000', EndDate = '2016-10-02 04:22:00.000'

This is because it returns only one row and the line "LAG(C.DateVal) OVER (ORDER BY C.RowId)" for calculating MinuteDiff returns NULL, there is no previous row to consider.

Can you help me on this?

Comment: Neer, I'm having bit of problem, when the time slots are as listed below:

Id | StartTime | EndTime | Points
---|--------------|--------------|-----------|
12 | 2:01 | 20:00 | 10
---|-------------|---------------|-----------|
14 | 20:01 | 2:00 | 20

The result I get is "NULL"

Parameters: StartDate  = '2016-10-02 00:41:00.000', EndDate = '2016-10-02 04:22:00.000'

This is because it returns only one row and the line "LAG(C.DateVal) OVER (ORDER BY C.RowId)" for calculating MinuteDiff returns NULL, there is no previous row to consider.

Can you help me on this?

Comment: @joe Looks like this query doesnt work `(SELECT T.EndTime FROM @Tbl T WHERE CAST(CurrentDate AS TIME) BETWEEN T.StartTime AND T.EndTime` Let me check

Comment: @Joe Problem is times. You should split times as `20:01 - 00:00` and `00:00 - 02:00` with same point value.