# Converting date time range into hourly data

Tags: sql

Hi this is my first post so if I don’t provide enough detail please let me know.
I have staff data for a rota and it’s summited start date and time one data entry and end date and time. I am trying to see the number of staff I got for any point in time.
I thought if I can create an hourly entry for the date time range. I can create an additional static table if needed.

Example
Current Data

```
+--------+---------------------+---------------------+
| Staff  |       Start time    |       End time      |
+--------+---------------------+---------------------+
| Staff1 | 01/04/2018 10:00:00 | 01/04/2018 18:00:00 |
| Staff2 | 01/04/2018 15:00:00 | 01/04/2018 20:00:00 |
+--------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Turn into

```
+---------+---------------------+
|  Staff  |    Hours worked     |
+---------+---------------------+
| Staff1  | 01/04/2018 10:00:00 |
| Staff1  | 01/04/2018 11:00:00 |
| Staff1  | 01/04/2018 12:00:00 |
| Staff1  | 01/04/2018 13:00:00 |
| Staff1  | 01/04/2018 14:00:00 |
| Staff1  | 01/04/2018 15:00:00 |
| Staff2  | 01/04/2018 15:00:00 |
| Staff1  | 01/04/2018 16:00:00 |
| Staff2  | 01/04/2018 16:00:00 |
| Staff1  | 01/04/2018 17:00:00 |
| Staff2  | 01/04/2018 17:00:00 |
| Staff1  | 01/04/2018 18:00:00 |
| Staff2  | 01/04/2018 18:00:00 |
| Staff2  | 01/04/2018 19:00:00 |
| Staff2  | 01/04/2018 20:00:00 |
+---------+---------------------+
```

I would then be able to split the date and time and then pivot in excel to see how many staff cover I have for a particular time and date.

If there is another way I am open to any ideas. Many thanks
Steven

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select all hours between two dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27161474/how-to-select-all-hours-between-two-dates)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Steven. Take a look at [this post](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips and tools for formatting data and code in your questions.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Haag1 thanks for the link to another post, gives me something to try and see how far I get

Comment: Eric many thanks for the edits, tried to lay it out like that but was on my phone and didn’t really work.

Comment: If you want to know how many staff were working at a specific date/time, why are you trying to achieve this in Excel instead of just querying for the result? `SELECT * FROM table WHERE start_time <= ':date' AND end_time >= ':date';`. Simply replace the `:date` parameter with your desired date/time.

Comment: "SQL" as a tag just does NOT tell us enough to propose a full solution. Oracle, Postgres, MySQL, Ms SQL Server, SQLite, Firebird...... that are too many dialects of SQL. Often it is important to know the version as well e.g. MySQL 5.7 is different to MySQL 8.0