# Splitting Start Date Time End Date Time Into Hourly Duration Per Day

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this:

```
Work Center Name  Start Date                    Stop Date
AA                2020-02-25 19:25:21.25212521  2020-02-25 20:02:44.244244
AA                2020-02-25 08:56:20.56205620  2020-02-25 09:16:33.16331633
AA                2020-02-25 14:32:04.324324    2020-02-25 14:34:38.34383438
AA                2020-02-25 15:21:54.21542154  2020-02-25 15:26:24.26242624
AA                2020-02-25 15:07:28.728728    2020-02-25 15:11:25.11251125
AA                2020-02-25 14:08:56.856856    2020-02-25 14:11:41.11411141
AA2               2020-06-09 19:34:11.34113411  2020-06-10 09:29:45.29452945
```

Essentially I have a start date and time and I would like to show a date and a duration in hours for each day.

**Expected output:**

[image]

Is this possible?

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: A large number of people who might help you won't see that image. You should use formatted text to show that information instead.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want:

```
select name, convert(date, startdate),
       sum(datediff(minute, startdate, enddate)) / 60.0 as hours
from t
group by name, convert(date, startdate);
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, Thank you so much for answering. Unfortunately this just gives me the difference between the start and end attributed to the start date. However I have some which span two days. So therefore what I would really like is the number of hours within that day. In the picture I posted this is shown against AA2. Do you know how to do this? Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I have come up with this ugly solution - keeping in mind that the duration of work can be more than a day. I have had to use a table valued function that returns the MINUTES (instead of hours from prev version of answer) between a start and end date time.

See the code below for the function (thanks for this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27161879/65347)

```
go

create function dbo.minutes_between_start_end
(
@minDateTime DATETIME2
,@maxDateTime DATETIME2
)

returns @t table (Date_Value date, Hour_Value datetime2) 

As

BEGIN


DECLARE @hrsDiff INT;
SELECT @hrsDiff = DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @minDateTime, @maxDateTime);

WITH E1(N) AS (
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
),
E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), 
E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), 
Tally(N) AS(SELECT row_number() over(order by (select null)) from E4) -- Numbered rrow

insert into @t(Date_Value, Hour_Value)
SELECT 
cast(@minDateTime as date)      as [Date_Value] 
,@minDateTime                   as [Hour_Value]

UNION ALL

SELECT 

cast(DATEADD(MINUTE, N, @minDateTime) as date)  as [Date_Value] 

, CASE 
    when DATEADD(MINUTE, N, @minDateTime) > @maxDateTime THEN   @maxDateTime
    else DATEADD(MINUTE, N, @minDateTime)
END as [Hour_Value]

FROM 

Tally
WHERE
    N <= @hrsDiff
;
return

END

GO
```

With the function, I have cross-joined the the function output and multiple CTEs to come up with the output.

```
/* Test table and test data */
declare @test table
(
work_center varchar(10)
,start_date datetime
,end_date datetime
)

insert into @test(work_center, start_date, end_date)
select 'AA', '2020-02-25 19:25:21.25212521',  '2020-02-25 20:02:44.244244' union
select 'AA', '2020-02-25 08:56:20.56205620',  '2020-02-25 09:16:33.16331633' union
select 'AA', '2020-02-25 14:32:04.324324',  '2020-02-25 14:34:38.34383438' union
select 'AA', '2020-02-25 15:21:54.21542154',  '2020-02-25 15:26:24.26242624' union
select 'AA', '2020-02-25 15:07:28.728728',  '2020-02-25 15:11:25.11251125' union
select 'AA', '2020-02-25 14:08:56.856856',  '2020-02-25 14:11:41.11411141' union
select 'AA2','2020-06-09 19:34:11.34113411',  '2020-06-10 09:29:45.29452945' UNION
select 'aa3', '2020-06-09 19:34:11', '2020-06-11 09:29:45' -- case > 1 day

/* table a1 with rows for each hour between start and end time */
;with a1 as
(
select * 
from 
@test t

cross apply

dbo.minutes_between_start_end(start_date, end_date)
)
--select * from a1 
,a2 as
(
    select work_center, Date_Value, count(1) as total_minute_per_day 
    from a1 
    group by 
    work_center, Date_Value
)

select 
*
, cast(total_minute_per_day/60.00 as decimal(4,2)) total_hour_per_day  
from a2
```

The result returned is given below. Note that I have one entry spanning for more than 24 hrs.

[image]

Comment: I have made a correction to my previous solution. Instead of hours between start and end time, my table values function now returns number of minutes. You can then just group it by work center and date to get the required result.

Comment: @Mike P - You can modify my solution and table-values function to use DATETIME2 as your data type is different from what I have used in my example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Case to force the end of the current day, and a Union to include the records that end the following day:

```
select [Work Center] =  [Work Center Name], 
       StartDate = convert(date, [Start Date]),
       Duration = cast(sum(datediff(minute, [Start Date], (Case when convert(date, [Stop Date]) > convert(date, [Start Date]) then convert(date, [Stop Date]) --If record ends following day, calculate only until start of following day.
                                                        else [Stop Date] 
                                                    end) ) ) / 60.0 as decimal(5,1) )
from yourTable
group by [Work Center Name], convert(date, [Start Date])
Union
select [Work Center] =  [Work Center Name],
       StartDate = convert(date, [Stop Date]),
       Duration = cast(sum(datediff(minute, convert(date, [Stop Date]), [Stop Date]) ) / 60.0 as decimal(5,1) )                                     
from yourTable
where convert(date, [Stop Date]) > convert(date, [Start Date]) --Only records that end the following day
group by [Work Center Name], convert(date, [Stop Date])
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Will it work if the start and end date covers more than 1 day? I have not tested it myself, being lazy, just asking the question.