Populate rows with all datetime values in a period?
I'm looking to populate a column in a table with a value for every hour between two dates.
Example:
01-01-2020 00:00:00 to 01-01-2026 00:00:00

should produce this result:
01-01-2020 00:00:00
01-01-2020 01:00:00
01-01-2020 02:00:00
...
31-12-2025 22:00:00
31-12-2025 23:00:00
31-12-2025 22:00:00
01-01-2026 00:00:00

I know that I need DATEADD and DATEDIFF but I'm not figuring out the correct SQL statement for this

This is a bad idea; this means your row needs to have 365724 columns; that's far too wide.

Similar question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27161474/how-to-select-all-hours-between-two-dates

What you should really do is invest in a calendar table and time table, then you can generate these as rows.

When you say "populate row" do you really mean "populate column" ? Your desired results appear to be multiple rows

@MartinSmith - that's after someone else (not OP) edited the post.

@Andrew - they just formatted it as code. The original post still had all the line breaks https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/619bb8e7-34a4-459a-b8af-e73416357faa/view-source

@MartinSmith thats right it's column not row, that was a mistake

What version of SQL Server? A recent release added a feature that can make this easier.

If GENERATE_SERIES is not an option
Example
Declare @D1 datetime = '2020-01-01 00:00:00'
Declare @D2 datetime = '2026-01-01 00:00:00'

Select DTCol = dateadd(hour,N,@D1)
 From ( Select Top (Select datediff(hour,@D1,@D2)+1) N=-1+Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select NULL)) From master..spt_values n1, master..spt_values n2 ) A

Results
DTCol
2020-01-01 00:00:00.000
2020-01-01 01:00:00.000
2020-01-01 02:00:00.000
...
2025-12-31 22:00:00.000
2025-12-31 23:00:00.000
2026-01-01 00:00:00.000


The use of the under documented spt_values table is debateable https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4273723/what-is-the-purpose-of-system-table-master-spt-values-and-what-are-the-meanings

@BartMcEndree ANY table of adequate size will do.

hello thanks for the answers with the help of gpt this code made what i needed
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = '2020-01-01 00:00:00';
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME = '2026-01-01 00:00:00';

DECLARE @currentDatetime DATETIME = @StartDate;

WHILE @currentDatetime < @EndDate
BEGIN

    DECLARE @valor INT = FLOOR(RAND() * 101);
    
    DECLARE @randomBit BIT = CASE WHEN RAND() < 0.5 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END;
    
    INSERT INTO teste (
        TimeStamp,
        Value_1,
        Value_2
        Value_3
        )
    VALUES (
        @currentDatetime,
        @valor,
        FLOOR(RAND() * 101),  
        @randomBit,          
     
    );
    
    SET @currentDatetime = DATEADD(HOUR, 1, @currentDatetime);
END


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
